# Get a tranposed table w/o creating a new table

Tags: sqlite

I have a SQLite table

```
 id     name      value
 1       n1        v1
 1       n2        v2
 2       n1        v3
 2       n2        v4
 3       n1        v5
 3       n2        v6
```

And I wanted to get a table like the following

```
 id      n1        n2
 1       v1        v2
 2       v3        v4
 3       v5        v6
```

we can see in the old table id is not unique, while after transposing id is unique in the new table. The number of n is not known, but each id should have the same number of n.

Is there a way that I can get the transposed table by a SQLite query w/o creating a new table?

Comment: Is the number of output columns fixed, i.e. are there only 2 (`n1` and `n2`)?

Comment: @redneb No. They are not fixed. They could be n1, n2, ... n5. But each id should have the same number of n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to do that in sqlite with a single query. The only think you can do is to retrieve the list of all possible names with something like

```
SELECT DISTINCT name FROM t ORDER BY name
```

and then dynamically construct the a query that will produce the desired result, such as the following (assuming that there are only names: `n1` and `n2`):

```
SELECT t0.id, t1.value AS n1, t2.value AS n2
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM t ORDER BY id) t0
     LEFT JOIN t t1 ON t0.id=t1.id AND t1.name='n1'
     LEFT JOIN t t2 ON t0.id=t2.id AND t2.name='n2';
```

Alternatively, you can use a correlated subquery, but it will probably be slower:

```
SELECT
    id,
    (SELECT value FROM t WHERE id=t0.id AND name='n1') AS n1,
    (SELECT value FROM t WHERE id=t0.id AND name='n2') AS n2
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM t ORDER BY id) t0;
```

Comment: What are t1 and t2 in these queries?

Comment: They are aliases for the subqueries so that I can refer to some of their columns.